# How to overlap a subfigure into multiple rows

Tags: graphics, formatting, subfig

I'm trying to produce figures in a 3x2 pattern with an additional figure on the right overlapping both rows. I was able to produce this in beamer, it looks like this:

[image: beamer figures]

I used the column environment, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Results}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
    
    \vspace{-1em}
    \begin{columns}
    \hspace{-2.5em}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=0).png}
            \vspace{-1.1em}
            \caption{time = 0}
        \end{figure}
        \vspace{-1em}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=15).png}
            \vspace{-1.1em}
            \caption{time = 15 mins}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
        \hspace{-2.5cm}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=5).png}
            \vspace{-1.1em}
            \caption{time = 5 mins}
        \end{figure}
        \vspace{-1em}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=20).png}
            \vspace{-1.1em}
            \caption{time = 20 mins}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
        \hspace{-2.5cm}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=10).png}
            \vspace{-1.1em}
            \caption{time = 10 mins}
        \end{figure}
        \vspace{-1em}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=25).png}
            \vspace{-1.1em}
            \caption{time = 25 mins}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \hspace{-3.5cm}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \vspace{-1cm}
            \includegraphics[width=1.3cm, height=4.5cm]{Figures/colorbar.png}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

I want to duplicate this inside an article document class. As far as I can tell article class doesn't support the use of columns so I've tried to use subfigure to reproduce this. However I can't get the rightmost figure to overlap both rows. Here is what it looks like:

[image: article figures]

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=0).png}
            \caption{time = 0}
            \label{fig:subfig1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=5).png}
            \caption{time = 5 minutes}
            \label{fig:subfig2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=10).png}
            \caption{time = 10 minutes}
            \label{fig:subfig3}
        \end{subfigure}
    \vfill
         \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
             \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=15).png}
             \caption{time = 15 minutes}
             \label{fig:subfig4}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
              \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=20).png}
              \caption{time = 20 minutes}
              \label{fig:subfig5}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Figures/u(t=25).png}
            \caption{time = 25 minutes}
            \label{fig:subfig6}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1cm]{Figures/colorbar.png}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Heat diffusion over time}
    \label{fig:subfigures4}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Answer (score 2):

A `subfigure` environment is a `minipage` environment that's been told what to do when it encounters a `\caption` statement. I suggest you enclose the first six `subfigure` environment in a separate `minipage` environment, and then place the final `subfigure` next to the `minipage`.

Oh, and don't set absolute widths for the graphs, as in `\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{...}`. Instead, use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}`, where `\linewidth` is the (relative) width of the enclosing `subfigure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption} % caption is loaded automatically by subcaption
\usepackage{subcaption}
   
\begin{document}
   
\begin{figure}
   
   \begin{minipage}[c]{0.86\textwidth} % start an "outer" minipage
      \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/u(t=0).png}
        \caption{time = 0}
        \label{fig:subfig1}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \hspace{0.01\textwidth}%
      \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/u(t=5).png}
        \caption{time = 5 min}
        \label{fig:subfig2}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \hspace{0.01\textwidth}%
      \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/u(t=10).png}
        \caption{time = 10 min}
        \label{fig:subfig3}
      \end{subfigure}% leave a blank line to create a line break
   
      \medskip
      \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/u(t=15).png}
        \caption{time = 15 min}
        \label{fig:subfig4}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \hspace{0.01\textwidth}%
      \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/u(t=20).png}
        \caption{time = 20 min}
        \label{fig:subfig5}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \hspace{0.01\textwidth}%
      \begin{subfigure}{0.28\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/u(t=25).png}
        \caption{time = 25 min}
        \label{fig:subfig6}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \end{minipage}%
      \hspace{0.01\textwidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[c]{0.13\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                         height=7cm] % set height as needed
                        {Figures/colorbar.png}
      \end{minipage}
      
\caption{Heat diffusion over time}
\label{fig:subfigures4}
   
\end{figure}
   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of nice @Mico answer (+1). If you have installed `subcaption` package version 3.1 or newer, than you can use the `sublot` (as defined in `subfig` package) and `\setkeys{Gin}{...}` macro, both contribute to much shorter code:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % version 3.1 or newer

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.86\textwidth} % start an "outer" minipage
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.33\linewidth}
%
\subfloat[time = 0 min \label{fig:subfig1}]{\includegraphics{Figures/u(t=0).png}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[time = 5min  \label{fig:subfig2}]{\includegraphics{Figures/u(t=5).png}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[time = 10min \label{fig:subfig3}]{\includegraphics{Figures/u(t=10).png}}%

\medskip
 \subfloat[time = 15 min \label{fig:subfig4}]{\includegraphics{Figures/u(t=15).png}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[time = 20min  \label{fig:subfig5}]{\includegraphics{Figures/u(t=20).png}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[time = 25min \label{fig:subfig6}]{\includegraphics{Figures/u(t=25).png}}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.12\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=7cm]{Figures/colorbar.png}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Heat diffusion over time}
\label{fig:subfigures4}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]